# Displaying images in rails/ javascript in frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How do I add support for displaying images in general in frontend in a rails application? From backend I get imageId as string  ("imageId": "string"). I also use Javascript/jQuery in the frontend.

Comment: could you add an example of what are you trying to do? Right now your problem doesn't seem clear to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%= image_path('image.png') %>` in js.erb/json.jbuilder views. If you need to recieve images from static .js/.coffe files that bad, there is js_assets gem, which adds asset_path method in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format(erb/haml), you can simply use image html tag or rails tag like this image_tag("icon.png", size: "16x10", alt: "Edit Entry") and if you want to use javascript along with that , define an id or class within the image tag and make changes in JS